# Cannot Connect to sql server using alias created with Sql Server Client Network Utility

Tags: sql-server, alias

I have created an alias to a Sql Server
with cliconfg.exe (Sql Server Client Network Utility) as below
(according to [Setting Up a SQL Server Alias](http://mmman.itgroove.net/2013/11/03/setting-up-a-sql-server-alias-with-sharepoint-server-2013/)):

Server Alias: MyAliasSqlServer/Myinstance

Server Name: MysqlServer/Myinstance

Port: 1433

Unfortunately the alias doesn't work as 
connecting with ODBC Data Source Administrator I get:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.3000

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

TESTS FAILED!
```

The TCP/IP is enabled on the server and I manage to connect with the server name.
I have set aliases for both 32bit and 64bit
I have tryed setting alias on the sql Sever via Sql Server Configuration Manager
What else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use a backslash "\" instead of the forward slash.